# Nginx: Selectively enable compression based on referrer hostname

Tags: nginx, http-referer, breach-attack

In order to mitigate against the BREACH attack, I would like to selectively enable gzip only when `$http_referer`'s hostname matches one of my server names.

How would I do this? I tried using `valid_referers server_names;`, but it seems like nginx doesn't allow `gzip on` inside if statements. When I include this in my conf:

```
valid_referers server_names;

if ($invalid_referer = "") {
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
}
```

I get `[emerg] "gzip" directive is not allowed here`. The must be a way to selectively enable gzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip) specifies that the `gzip` option is allowed in the following contexts

> `Context: http, server, location, if in location`

This means you need to wrap the `gzip` switch inside a `location` block.

```
gzip  off;

server {
  listen 80; 
  server_name localhost;
  valid_referers server_names;

  location / { 
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    if ($invalid_referer = "") {
       gzip on; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: However, using `if` in a location context has issue: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/